# Not getting the table data with table header in proper format in Laravel 'friendofphp/goutte' web-scraping

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, datatables, goutte

```
$client = new Client();
      
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=EnegzCwAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao');
$crawler->filter('#gsc_a_t')->each(function ($item) {
    $header = $item->filter('th')->first();
    $data = $item->filter('td')->first();
    $this->results[$header->text()] = $item->filter('td')->first()->text();

    dd($item->filter('#gsc_a_b')->text());
});
```

Getting the data in a clumsy format and I wanted to print whole table data in exact format as its shown on the website with the links on it. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution.

I want to store tr in `tr[]` td in `td[]` and tabledatalinks in `tdlink[]` and then just display the exact format as its shown in my view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am crawling on the given link and extracting the table data but the data is not in the proper format I mean I am just getting it like a whole paragraph, what I wanted is to store data in the array and then display it on the laravel view page.